# SwiftUI .popover on tap of Map Marker

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I'm trying to get a `.popover` to work with a Map > Marker but can't seem to get it. I've tried to go about this by getting the coordinates and presenting a `.popover` based on that, but I can't get it to work. Simply putting the `.popover` modifier on `Image("Logo")` didn't seem to work either. Here is my current code

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    var libraries: [Library]
    @State private var selectedLibrary: Library?

    init(libraries: [Library]) {
        if let firstLibrary = libraries.first {
            _region = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: firstLibrary.coordinate,
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)
            ))
        } else {
            _region = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion())
        }
        self.libraries = libraries
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map {
                ForEach(libraries) { library in
                    Marker(coordinate: library.coordinate) {
                        Image("Logo")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    }
                    .tint(.purple)
                }
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ForEach(libraries) { library in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedLibrary = library
                    }, label: {
                        Color.clear
                    })
                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                    .position(self.coordinateToPoint(library.coordinate, in: geometry))
                    .popover(isPresented: Binding<Bool>(
                        get: { self.selectedLibrary == library },
                        set: { if !$0 { self.selectedLibrary = nil } }
                    )) {
                        Text("Annotation details here")
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func coordinateToPoint(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGPoint {
        let mapWidthDegrees = region.span.longitudeDelta
        let mapHeightDegrees = region.span.latitudeDelta

        let widthPerDegree = geometry.size.width / mapWidthDegrees
        let heightPerDegree = geometry.size.height / mapHeightDegrees

        let xCoordinate = (coordinate.longitude - region.center.longitude + mapWidthDegrees / 2) * widthPerDegree
        let yCoordinate = (region.center.latitude - coordinate.latitude + mapHeightDegrees / 2) * heightPerDegree

        return CGPoint(x: xCoordinate, y: yCoordinate)
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView(libraries: LibraryData.libraries)
    }
}
```

And here is my LibraryData and Library for reference

```swift
import CoreLocation

struct Library: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    static func == (lhs: Library, rhs: Library) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id &&
        lhs.coordinate.latitude == rhs.coordinate.latitude &&
        lhs.coordinate.longitude == rhs.coordinate.longitude
    }
}

struct LibraryData {
    static let libraries = [
        Library(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33182, longitude: -122.03118)),
        Library(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.34182, longitude: -122.03218)),
        Library(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.34182, longitude: -122.04118))
    ]
}
```

When I tap the marker inside the map nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a different approach using `Annotation` instead of `Marker` and the `.popover()`.

The example code shows how to tap on any `Annotation` and popup a custom view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapView(libraries: LibraryData.libraries)
    }
}

struct MapView: View {
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    var libraries: [Library]
    @State private var selectedLibrary: Library?
    
    // for testing
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .camera(
        MapCamera(centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33182, longitude: -122.03118), distance: 8000.0, heading: 0, pitch: 0)
    )
    
    init(libraries: [Library]) {
        if let firstLibrary = libraries.first {
            _region = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: firstLibrary.coordinate,
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)
            ))
        } else {
            _region = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion())
        }
        self.libraries = libraries
    }
    
    @State private var toggler = false  // <-- here to toggle the popup view
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $cameraPosition) {
            ForEach(libraries) { library in
                Annotation("", coordinate: library.coordinate) {
                    ZStack {
                        Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedLibrary = library
                                toggler.toggle()
                            }
                            .foregroundStyle(.white, .purple)
                        if selectedLibrary == library && toggler {
                            PopupView(library: selectedLibrary)
                        } else {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

// just for testing, adjust the looks as needed
 struct PopupView: View {
    @State var library: Library?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let lib = library {
                Text("Poping: \(String(lib.id.uuidString.prefix(4)))")
            } else {
                Text("no data")
            }
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.purple)
        .frame(width: 120, height: 100)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .shadow(radius: 5)
        .offset(x: 0, y: -70)
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

you can use a `.popover(...)` if this is really what you want.
I feel it does not looks great on ios devices, but looks good on mac/macCatalyst and iPad, and the `Button` works.

```
struct MapView: View {
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    var libraries: [Library]
    
    // for testing
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .camera(
        MapCamera(centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33182, longitude: -122.03118), distance: 8000.0, heading: 0, pitch: 0)
    )
    
    init(libraries: [Library]) {
        if let firstLibrary = libraries.first {
            _region = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: firstLibrary.coordinate,
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)
            ))
        } else {
            _region = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion())
        }
        self.libraries = libraries
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $cameraPosition) {
            ForEach(libraries) { library in
                Annotation("", coordinate: library.coordinate) {
                    MakerView(library: library)
                }
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
    
}

struct MakerView: View {
    @State var library: Library
    @State private var showPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
            Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showPopover = true
                }
                .foregroundStyle(.white, .purple)

        .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
            Text("Annotation details here")
            Button("click me"){
                print("----> Button clicked")
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I did notice though is that if I add a button underneath the Text view inside the PopupView, the action doesn't seem to be working. I wonder if that's because of some Map layer or something. I may need to reconsider this popover idea.

Comment: are you targetting MacOS or ios?

Comment: I'm targeting iOS.

Comment: updated my answer with using just a `.popover`. I am also noticing the glitch with the button (and other tapGestures). It seems the custom `PopupView` is not on top to receive the tap.

Comment: Yep, I think that will have to work. Thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated.